# How to apply Kruskal Wallis test on censored varibles in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data set of Chromium measurements in different brands of bottled waters. I would like to apply Kruskal-Wallis H test to determine if there are statistically significant differences between brands of chromium, but there are many censored values in the measured data.

Is there any way to apply Kruskal-Wallis H test on this censored variable. Our dataset `df` is pasted below:

```
df <- structure(list(
       Brand = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
           3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
           4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
           5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5"), class = "factor"), 
       Chromium = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.9, 0.4, 1.3, 1.3, 0.4, 2.6, 
           0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 2.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 1.3, 
           1.3, 0.4, 2.6, 0.4, 0.7, 0.7, 0.4, 1.7, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.4,            
           0.4, 0.4, 1.3, 1.3, 0.4, 2.6, 0.4, 1.1, 1, 0.4, 1.5, 0.4, 
           0.7, 0.4, 0.4, 1, 0.4, 1.3, 1.3, 0.4, 2.6, 0.4, 1, 1.1, 0.4, 
           2.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1.3, 1.3, 0.4, 2.6, 0.4, 
           0.6, 0.7, 0.4, 1.8, 0.4)), .Names = c("Brand", "Chromium"), 
           class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -75L))

head(df)
#   Brand Chromium
# 1    B1      0.4
# 2    B1      0.4
# 3    B1      0.4
# 4    B1      0.9
# 5    B1      0.4
# 6    B1      1.3
```

Comment: Do you want to ignore censored variables?

Comment: No Eli, I'd like to consider the censored values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider the "cendiff" function in the [NADA package for R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NADA/NADA.pdf). According to the documentation, it is equivalent to the Peto & Peto modification of the Gehan-Wilcoxon test (Generalized Wilcoxon Test). This is a score test designed to handle data censored at multiple reporting limits using survival analysis. There is a more extensive description in Section 9.4 of Dennis R. Helsel's book "Statistics for Censored Environmental Data Using Minitab and R", second edition.

Answer (score 1):

`< 0.4` is the smallest value that `Chromium` can take in your data. The Kruskal-Wallis test relies on the ranks of the values, instead of the actual values. This implies that you can simply replace `< 0.4` with `0.39`, because they will have the same rank assigned to them as before. Actually, you can replace `< 0.4` with *any* value smaller than 0.4.

In code, that would be:

```
df$Chromium[df$Chromium == "< 0.4"] <- 0.4
```

Make sure that your data is numeric and then you can just run:

```
kruskal.test(Chromium ~ Brand, 
         data = df)
# Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

# data:  Chromium by Brand
# Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 0.51334, df = 4, p-value = 0.9722
```

Answer (score 1):

Whereas I agree with the first answer (replacing <0.4 by 0.4 is valid in principle), the large number of values below detection limit (ending up as ties in the ranking) may reduce the power of your Kruskal-Wallis test considerably.
As an alternative, you could consider using a chi-square test to see if the proportion of values above threshold level differs between brands. In the case of your example:

```
xm<-rbind(c(8,8,4),c(7,7,1))
dimnames(xm)<-list(scores=c("Low","High"),brand=c("B1","B2","B3"))
print(xm)
(xmcs<-chisq.test(xm,simulate.p.value = T))
```

which yields:

```
> print(xm)
      brand
scores B1 B2 B3
  Low   8  8  4
  High  7  7  1
> (xmcs<-chisq.test(xm,simulate.p.value = T))

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  xm
X-squared = 1.2444, df = NA, p-value = 0.7216
```

Equally non-significant difference between brands as in Kruskal-Wallis test

Comment: I see your point with the power reduction. However, doesn't it seem unnecessary to "artificially censor" the data once more and loose even more information than was lost already?